# Problems with dialogflow with Node JS send messages at the same time

Tags: node.js, facebook, dialogflow-es

I'm new to developing dialogflow chatbot with Node JS so I chose facebook platform to do it. I have managed to connect successfully including saving users to a database etc. Now I wanted to go a step further and start creating conversation flows and here a problem has arisen. It turns out that I need to collect information from a user when he wants to create an appointment but first I want to know how the message flow works with Node JS. The first thing I have done is create the intention and associate it to an action to manipulate the code from Node JS as shown in the image:

[image]

Then I have created a Switch where it calls each Action according to the defined name and there it calls each function. My function is simple is the following:

```
  async function handleCreateAppointment(sender) {
    await sendTextMessage(sender, "give me your name");

    await sendTextMessage(sender, "give me your lastname");

  }
```

The method that is defined and I got it from a SentTextMessage tutorial is the following

```
async function sendTextMessage(recipientId, text) {
  if (text.includes("{first_name}") || text.includes("{last_name}")) {
    let userData = await getUserData(recipientId);
    text = text
      .replace("{first_name}", userData.first_name)
      .replace("{last_name}", userData.last_name);
  }
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId,
    },
    message: {
      text: text,
    },
  };
  await callSendAPI(messageData);
}
```

And just to complement I'm using these libraries:

```
//libraries
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const request = require("request");
const uuid = require("uuid");
const axios = require("axios");
```

As you can see, the two messages come out at the same time and I would like to know how I can get a message to come out first and then the following message appears after the user of the response.

[image]